# For SAP GUI script, do you know what is the script for SAP job has been created?

Tags: excel, typescript, sap-erp, sap-gui

I have created a SAP GUI script to script the transaction code `F110`.

Is there a way or script to determine the SAP job has been created?

Meaning that once the job is created, my SAP macro excel able to move to next line and continue for the next command.

Can anyone help? Thanks in ton!

[image]

Comment: As in your screenshot check with your script if the status is _green_.

Comment: Name of the field is `wnd[0]/usr/tabsF110_TABSTRIP/tabpSTA/ssubSUBSCREEN_BODY:SAPF110V:0201/sub:SAPF110V:0201/txtF110V-STATU[1,0]`